# Swift Use of unresolved identifier 'RealmApp'

Tags: swift, realm, mongodb-realm

I was following this Realm ios SDK quickstart
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/quick-start/

here is my swift code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift
import UIKit



let app = RealmApp(id: "xxxx")
```

however i keep getting this error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'RealmApp'

this is my pod file

```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your
```

project
platform :ios, '12.0'

```
  target 'Emma' do
   # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

   # Pods for Emma
   pod 'Firebase'
   pod 'RealmSwift', '=10.0.0-beta.2'

   target 'EmmaTests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
   end

    target 'EmmaUITests' do
      # Pods for testing
    end

    end
```

RealmSwift module has been installed through the pod file. I don't know how to resolve the issue since that is what is listed in the quick start.

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using? Did you follow the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/install/)?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.  At some point it seems `let app = RealmApp(id: "xxxx")` was changed to `let app = App(id: "xxxx")`.